# writing elements of $\mathbb Z_5[x]/I$

Tags: ring-theory

If I have ring $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ ,and let $I=\langle x^2+x+2 \rangle$,then if I have to represent the elements of
$\mathbb Z_5[x]/I$ they'll be of form :

$$\{a+bx+I\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z_5\},$$

I still can't understand how can we represent them in the above form ,i.e. why did we write elements from $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ as $a+bx\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z_5$.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We mod out by $x^2 + x + 2$, so we identify this last polynomial by $0$ in the quotient ring. This means that $x^2 + x  +2 \equiv 0$ or $x^2 \equiv -x - 2 \equiv 4x + 3$, as we take coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. So also $x^3 \equiv x^2 \cdot x \equiv 4x^2 + 3x \equiv 4(-x-2) + 3x$, etc.

So all squares (and it follows from that, all higher powers of $x$ as well) can be replaced by linear terms. So a member of the quotient is represented by some polynomial (any order). but we reduce all higher than linear terms to linear terms, and get a representation as a linear polynomial.

Comment: in your answer you showed $x^3$ can be written as like $ax+b|a,b\in \mathbb Z_5$ ,but how can any element in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ be written such a way..... Please explain...

Comment: Show by induction that all $x^n$ can be written this way. Then in a polynomial reduce all powers separately, and a sum of linear terms is still linear.